# Jquery thickbox url stripping

Tags: jquery, thickbox

I am using jquery thickbox to show images and it works just fine but I am trying to add a click counter to update the database and when I add it, it makes thickbox not work and I am wondering if there is a way to strip the first part of the url

when I add in the click counter using php the links look like this

ttp://example.com/include/media_counter.php?url=http://example.com/image.jpg

Is there a way to make thick box strip ttp://example.com/include/media_counter.php?url= from the url and only use picture link? I want to be able to use both options "click counter and thickbox".

here is what my php looks like with the media counter and thick box will open but show no picture.

```
echo '<div class="images"><a href="'.$link_click.''.$row['media'].'"class="thickbox"><img src="'.$row['im_t_link'].'" height="100px" width="133px" title="'.$row[im_title].'"></a></div>';
```

if I remove $link_click it will work fine like this.

```
    echo '<div class="images"><a href="''.$row['media'].'"class="thickbox"><img src="'.$row['im_t_link'].'" height="100px" width="133px" title="'.$row[im_title].'"></a></div>';
```

any idea what I can do to resolve this? I am not good with javascript and such so I am looking for some help from people that do. Thanks.

Sorry I have the H taken from hyperlinks, Since I am a new user it only allows me one on here.

Comment: Are you 'submitting' the click for the counter via AJAX?

Comment: here is the thickbox i am using by the way http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

Comment: no I am not. I am not sure how to do that. I am just using php.

Comment: this is the sql query I am using in php if that helps. mysql_query ("update ".$mysql_table_prefix."media set click_counter=click_counter+1, last_click='$time', last_query='$query' where media_link = '$url' LIMIT 1");

Comment: One of the problems you'll have in any case, once you solve the image source issue, is, that you can't use the link for the counter. If you click the link, the thickbox will prevent the default (=sending the browser to the destination for this link) which will prevent your PHP script from ever registering the click. What comes to URL, hold on a sec and I'll try to throw together a fiddle as answer. Not sure yet what the best solution is…

Comment: not sure if you were asking "What comes to url," as a question but if so I am using    $url    = trim(substr ($_GET['url'], 0, 1024)); in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, counter via AJAX and `href` "rewrite" for Thickbox — place [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3b7qS/) in the `head` of your  HTML file and given that you have jQuery and the thickbox plugin included, that should do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function(){
        $('a.thickbox').each(function() {
            var $self = $(this),
                origHREF = this.href;

            $self
                .data('origHREF', origHREF)
                .attr('href', origHREF.split('?url=')[1])
                .click(function() {
                    $.get($(this).data('origHREF'));
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I am not sure how to get this to work. I will keep trying though. I really know basically nothing that is not php.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. it still wants to show http://example.com/include/media_counter.php?url=http://example.com/image.jpg I appreciate you trying to help me though. If I can't Figure something out I can live with one or the other. I was trying to create a last viewed images function and thats why i needed the click updated.

Comment: Okay. Do you happen to have it up somewhere to look at it?

Comment: No I don't I am running locally. It's okay though. I will figure something out. I appreciate your help.